# Getting variable from jQuery GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I need to get a variable from inside the GET request and use it inside the function. It's not working. Here is my code:

```
function chooseChosenOne() {

         $.get("generate.php", function(data) {
           var chosenOne = targetLocation[data.randomNumber];
         }, "json");

         alert(chosenOne);

       }
```

How can I fix this? How can I use the variable "chosenOne" outside of that function in the GET request?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the jQuery plugin [`getURLParam`](http://www.mathias-bank.de/2006/10/28/jquery-plugin-geturlparam/)

```
value = $.getURLParam("paramName");
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time you call `alert(chosenOne);`, the Ajax callback is not executed yet. Ajax is **asynchronous**. The function `chooseChosenOne` will not wait until the Ajax called finished, it will return immediately.

You can only work the return value in the callback:

```
function chooseChosenOne() {
     $.get("generate.php", function(data) {
         var chosenOne = targetLocation[data.randomNumber];
         alert(chosenOne); 
     }, "json");
}
```

So what you have to do is to make your function accept a callback which gets called as soon as the value is available:

```
function chooseChosenOne(callback) {
     $.get("generate.php", function(data) {
         callback(targetLocation[data.randomNumber]);
     }, "json");
}

chooseChosenOne(function(theOne) {
   // now do stuff with theOne here
});
```

See also:

- [*jQuery: Return data after ajax call success*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)
- What I have to say about [how to return data from an Ajax call.](http://thoughts.felix-kling.de/post/2743859538/how-to-return-data-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

'chosenOne' only exists inside your callback function, and your code will hit the alert() before the callback has even run...

```
function chooseChosenOne() {           
     $.get("generate.php", function(data) {            
                doSomethingWithChosenOne(targetLocation[data.randomNumber]);
               }, "json");
} 

function doSomethingWithChosenOne(v){
   alert(v);
}
```